# Erro Docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

Tags: docker

Sou novo no Docker e estou enfrentando um problema na hora de ver os container existentes ou qualquer outra informação.

Ao executar por exemplo :
                Docker ps. 
Apresenta a seguinte mensagem de erro:
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

O SO que estou usando é o Linux Ubuntu

Grato desde já.

Answer (score 3):

Verifique se o Docker [Daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/) está rodando com o comando `service docker status`, caso não estiver dê um start com `service docker start` e verifique se o erro persiste.

> Se o usuario docker não [pertencer ao mesmo grupo](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17645#issuecomment-153291483) do login usado
>   por você, adicione ele ao grupo, `sudo usermod -aG docker <seusuario>`

Caso persistir e puder reinstalar, faça com as instruções da documentação oficial, com ela terá a versão mais recente, mas antes remova a versão atual.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/

Comment: Fiz o processo informado, porem o problema continua. Ao rodar o comando 'service docker start', apresenta a seguinte mensagem: "start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.183" (uid=1000 pid=7036 comm="start docker ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
". Vou reinstalar e vou tentar novamente.

Comment: Siga os seguintes passos e seja feliz !!! https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#/create-a-docker-group